# Why isn't data loading on my Plotly chart?

Tags: javascript, flask, plotly

I have this webapp where the backend is built on Flask. I'm sending some numbers from my Python Flask script to my frontend using SocketIO, but i can't see the data loading on my chart.

I tried to debug it but there appears to be no error in my code. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //connect to the socket server.
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
  var numbers_received = [];


  //receive details from server
  socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
    console.log("Received" + msg.number);
    //maintain a list of ten numbers
    if (numbers_received.length >= 1) {
      numbers_received.shift()
    }

    numbers_received.push(msg.number);
    numbers_string = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++) {
      numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
    }
    $('#log').html(numbers_string);
  });


  Plotly.plot('chart',[{
      y:[numbers_received],
      type:'line'
  }]);

  var cnt = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
      Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[numbers_received]]}, [0]);
      cnt++;
      if(cnt > 500) {
          Plotly.relayout('chart',{
              xaxis: {
                  range: [cnt-500,cnt]
              }
          });
      }
  },15);


});
```